# vb.net 2010 picturebox array help

Tags: vb.net, arrays, visual-studio-2010, arraylist, picturebox

I am just wondering how i can create a picturebox array like i could when i copied and pasted another picturebox in VB6 and it asked me if i want to add them to an array. Doing so made them code like this:

```
picBox(0).enabled = true
picBox(1).enabled = true
etc etc..
```

But i am unable to do this using VB.net 2010! I'm sure there is a way to do that for each of my pictureboxs' on my form but i am unable to find out how!?

Any help would be great! :o)

David

Comment: Just to confirm, as SLaks is dealing with giving you actual alternatives, this feature was known as "Control Arrays" in VB6 and has indeed been removed completely from the language. SLaks' answer of explicitly defining a list of pictureboxes in code is probably the best alternative, these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a `PictureBox()` or a `List(Of PictureBox)` in the code-behind and add your pictureboxes to it in the constructor.
You can even populate the list by looping over the `Controls` collection of the container that holds the pictureboxes.

Comment: How would i do that if i have, say 3 pictureboxes on the form all named picBox1, picBox2 and picBox3? Would it be something like this: **Dim mypic() As PictureBox = {picbox1, picbox2, picBox3}**

Comment: @Stealth: Yes, except that you need to initialize it in the constructor. (Since the PictureBoxes are only created in `InitializeComponent`)

Comment: How would i go about making only one _Click event for all of them without having to do a **picBox1_Click** , **picBox2_Click** , etc...?

Comment: Make a single handler and add `Handles picBox1.Click, picBox2.Click, ...`.  Alternatively, call `AddHandler` in a loop.   In the handler, use the `sender` parameter.

Comment: @StealthRT: at the end of every Sub pictureBox1_Click() function, the line continues "Handles pictureBox1.Click". Handler methods are no longer defined by their name, they are defined by the "Handles" keyword, which is put after the method declaration. To have a method handle multiple methods, simply add those methods to the declaration; hence: "Handles pictureBox1.Click, pictureBox2.Click" etc.

Comment: Thanks for that, Frosty! :o) and thanks for the overall help, SLaks! :o)